# How to delete a cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete a cookie with this function , but it doesnt work..

```
deleteAllCookies();

function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Why the cookie is in my browser, even after i activate that function ...

Comment: How to you set the cookie? The `path` option must be exactly the same to delete it. Also, please ask only one question per thread.

Comment: I closed and opened my browser and it magically disappeared. What happens if i set time to 0 does it mean as soon as i close my browser the cookie disappears?

Comment: Why not set the cookie [to null](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)? `$.cookie("cookie_name", null);`

Comment: @AdamCaviness: Because that would require a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @AdamCaviness This is plain JavaScript, jQuery and the jQuery Cookie plugin was not mentioned.

Comment: someone voted to close..how was it?

Comment: how can i set the cookie so that with every request a new cookie is created is it by giving it 0

Comment: @Niko, I realize it requires jQuery but I think it's nice anyway.  I would have wanted someone to tell me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of deleting a cookie in JavaScript is to overwrite cookie's value to empty value and expires date to a passed date. Something like this.

**Example**, this should delete `acctoken` cookie.

```js
document.cookie = "acctoken=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;"
```

**If your cookie is in different domain or sub-doman**, then you will have to explicitly specify domain/sub-domain in overwritten cookie.

```js
document.cookie = "acctoken=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=example.com"
```

More, context in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917245/cannot-delete-cookie-by-using-javascript/57002934#57002934).

Answer (score -1):

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = cname + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT ; path = /;";
```

Answers above are correct but don't forget to add path