# Cannot delete cookie by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to use one cookie for all my pages and I want to update this cookie for all pages also. It will be used in layout as a theme value.

I have created a cookie named as theme by using javascript method;

```
$.cookie("theme", "skin-blue");
```

And checked the cookie whether is saved or not by using;

```
document.cookie "theme=skin-blue"
```

When i wanna delete the cookie by using it returns false;

```
$.removeCookie("theme") false
```

Can you help me to solve the issue? Is there anyway to delete or clear or cookies? Thanks.

Note: This method works for one page but not for all pages. In other pages it creates new cookie as same name so i cannot update the related one.

Comment: What did you think `$.removeCookie("theme") false` was going to do?

Comment: Is is possible to provide a plunker to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 i thought it should turn true and delete the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of deleting a cookie in JavaScript is to overwrite cookie's value to empty value and expires date to a passed date.

**Example:**
Let's say that cookie you'd like to delete is called `access_token`. Below line should deleted the cookie, **if cookie's domain is in the same domain**, then this should work. We assume that `access_token` cookie is in **example.com** domain.

```js
// Deleting access_token cookie with implicit domain.
document.cookie = "access_token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;"
```

**However**, If cookie's domain is in a different domain or a sub-domain **above line should not work**. Let me be more precise. This time, we assume that `access_token` cookie is in **.example.com** sub-domain *(notice the dot in front of example.com)*. Then, **above line should not work**, thus cookie will not be deleted.

**Solution**, for cases where cookie is in a different domain/sub-domain, then **you have to explicitly specify domain/sub-domain name** while deleting cookie.

```js
// Deleting access_token cookie, with explicit domain/sub-domain
document.cookie = "access_token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; domain=.example.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the cookies date to expired, something like:

```
function removeCookie (name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Mon, 01 Mar 1980 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

so just doing `removeCookie("theme");`

would remove your theme cookie

Comment: Thanks,yes it is useful but what about deleting forever :)

Comment: @Cracker Don't know about you, but for me, it is gone forever when setting to null

Comment: If you do `$.cookie("theme", "skin-blue")` and then type `document.cookie` you will see it, if you type `$.cookie("theme", null);` and then type `document.cookie` it is gone, is it not?

Comment: @Cracker Hmm.. Weird, on my end it doesn't exist anymore using Chrome / Chrome dev tools, that's how I've always done it

Comment: really really weird anyway thanks for your advise. I try to  figure out.

Comment: if i dont change the page it clears cookie, define new value to cookie. But if i change the page it sets new cookie with the same name so it cannot delete the older one. So in my design two pages get two different cookie value, i need one cookie value for all pages. I hope you understand me.